# EmberJs error for excel parser

Tags: ember.js, electron

I am trying to integrate ember with electron and used XLSX parser inside services to read my local excel file, but when I am injecting it to my route, I am getting this error. Please help.

My service file:

```
   import Ember from 'ember';
const remote=require('electron').remote;
const fs=remote.require('fs');
const XLSX = require('xlsx');
var f = "c:\\Users\\rajeev\\Downloads\\Tableau\\SuperStoreUS_2015.xlsx";


export default Ember.Service.extend({


    ExcelToJson:function(f){

        var workbook = XLSX.readfile(f.toString());
        var worksheet=workbook.Sheets['Orders'];
        alert(worksheet);
                            }

});
```

My Route file where I am injecting the service:

```
      import Ember from 'ember';
    export default Ember.Route.extend({
    sheet: Ember.inject.service('sheet'),
    message: 'test',
    actions: {

        pressButton: function() {
            let sheet=Ember.get(this,'sheet').ExcelToJson();
            var testText = this.get('sheet').ExcelToJson();
            this.set('message',testText);
        }

        }
});
```

My template file:

```
<button class="button" {{action "pressButton"}}>press</button>
```

Error when running on electron:

```
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at Class.ExcelToJson (serviceeg.js:544)
    at Class.pressButton (serviceeg.js:516)
    at Router.triggerEvent (vendor.js:39675)
    at trigger (vendor.js:67017)
    at Router.trigger (vendor.js:68617)
    at Class.send (vendor.js:38863)
    at Class.send (vendor.js:42875)
    at vendor.js:22521
    at Object.flaggedInstrument (vendor.js:29424)
    at vendor.js:22520
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are seeing is being thrown by this line:

```
var workbook = XLSX.readfile(f.toString());
```

That's because your method that contains that line declares a local variable `f` that is conflicting with your service-level variable `f` which is your test file name. If you move that test filename into your `ExcelToJson` method you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

I think xlsx file consist of many xml files with data. One way to get the data is to extract those xml and parse them. I found this xlsx parser
[xlsx parser](https://gist.github.com/trevordixon/3375836)

```
xlsxParser = (function() {
function extractFiles(file) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    zip.createReader(new zip.BlobReader(file), function(reader) {
        reader.getEntries(function(entries) {
            async.reduce(entries, {}, function(memo, entry, done) {
                var files = ['xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml', 'xl/sharedStrings.xml'];
                if (files.indexOf(entry.filename) == -1) return done(null, memo);

                entry.getData(new zip.TextWriter(), function(data) {
                    memo[entry.filename.split('/').pop()] = data;
                    done(null, memo);
                });
            }, function(err, files) {
                if (err) deferred.reject(err);
                else deferred.resolve(files);
            });
        });
    }, function(error) { deferred.reject(error); });

    return deferred.promise();
}

function extractData(files) {
    var sheet = $(files['sheet1.xml']),
        strings = $(files['sharedStrings.xml']),
        data = [];

    var colToInt = function(col) {
        var letters = ["", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
        var col = $.trim(col).split('');

        var n = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
            n *= 26;
            n += letters.indexOf(col[i]);
        }

        return n;
    };

    var Cell = function(cell) {
        cell = cell.split(/([0-9]+)/);
        this.row = parseInt(cell[1]);
        this.column = colToInt(cell[0]);
    };

    var d = sheet.find('dimension').attr('ref').split(':');
    d = _.map(d, function(v) { return new Cell(v); });

    var cols = d[1].column - d[0].column + 1,
        rows = d[1].row - d[0].row + 1;

    _(rows).times(function() {
        var _row = [];
        _(cols).times(function() { _row.push(''); });
        data.push(_row);
    });

    sheet.find('sheetData row c').each(function(i, c) {
        var $cell = $(c),
            cell = new Cell($cell.attr('r')),
            type = $cell.attr('t'),
            value = $cell.find('v').text();

        if (type == 's') value = strings.find('si t').eq(parseInt(value)).text();

        data[cell.row - d[0].row][cell.column - d[0].column] = value;
    });

    return data;
}

return {
    parse: function(file) {
        return extractFiles(file).pipe(function(files) {
            return extractData(files);
        });
    }
}})();
```